# web.xml url-pattern is not resolving wildcards

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web.xml, request-mapping

I am running simple Spring MVC application. In web.xml, I used following mapping configuration:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern> <!-- root request -->
    <url-pattern>/endpoint/*</url-pattern> <!-- /endpoint/${name} -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

My controller is defined as:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView render(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
        ModelAndView genericRenderStructure = new ModelAndView();
        genericRenderStructure.setViewName("WEB-INF/views/index.jsp");
        genericRenderStructure.addObject("endpointName", name);

        return genericRenderStructure;
    }
```

And yet render function is not triggered when visiting the path `/endpoints/something`. When I change the url-pattern to particular variable name, like `<url-pattern>/endpoint/something</url-pattern>`, the page starts working on such url. Why doesn't the wildcard symbol match my "whatever" used in url? Is this the problem with RequestMapping value? I am using Tomcat server v9.0.

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

<display-name>Spring3 MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern> <!-- root request -->
    <url-pattern>/endpoint/*</url-pattern> <!-- /endpoint/${name} -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring-web-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.api.web.*" ></context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value></value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that `<url-pattern>/endpoint/*</url-pattern>` is considered a base which should be left our from RequestMapping controller. When used with `@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`, the url where controller gets triggered is concatenated version of the two - `/endpoint/endpoint/{name}`. The correct RequestMapping should therefore be `@RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of `<url-pattern></url-pattern>` mentioned, remove one of them and try instead of `/*` with `/` only.

This will might work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need for empty `<url-pattern></url-pattern>` pattern. But it seems that the first one is getting matched before the actual pattern can be reached. Use this setting:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/endpoint/*</url-pattern> <!-- /endpoint/${name} -->
    <url-pattern></url-pattern> <!-- root request -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: As far as I know empty <url-pattern> is used for handling requests on root ("/" url). Even if I swap them both or remove the empty one "endpoint/whatever" is not responding.

Comment: So why don't you add `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` for the root?